# Angular JS hidden field : saving ng-model with condition

Tags: angularjs, hidden-field

I have a hidden field, which is used to identify the category of the directive.

How can I bind the data as :

```
<input type = "hidden" ng-model="category = category.option.name == 'By Count Range' ? 'byCount' : 'byRate' ">
```

The above code is not assignable while compiling.

How can I solve this?

I'm not sure about my code, but I need to perform that condition check.

Comment: Your ternary is a little wrong. Try this: `ng-model="category.option.name == 'By Count Range' ? 'byCount' : 'byRate' "`

Comment: But category.option.name is another model object. What I need is to assign one string into hidden field based on the model value

Comment: Can you explain your ternary operation in plain english? Are you trying to change `ng-model` of the input based on the value of `category.option.name`?

Comment: I have a model data category.option.name. But it is a string value either "By Count Range " or " By Rate". 

In my form I need to send one value "byCountRange" or "byRate" because this is the key that I had used in main object. That is why I had used the hidden field. I hope it is clear now.

Comment: I am sorry but I still dont understand your intent. Why have hidden input if it does not have a value?

Comment: Then how can I send the value?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89791/discussion-between-jaykay-and-jahongir-rahmonov).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you have  with two options: By count range or by rate and depending on which one is selected you want to change the . right?

Then, you can do this in template:

```
<select name='...' ng-model='...' ng-change='updateOptions()'>
```

and in your controller:

```
$scope.updateOptions = function () {
    if ($scope.category.priceOrTransactionOption == 'By Count Range'){
      $scope.categoryOptions = $scope.category.byCountRange.tiers
    }else{
      $scope.categoryOptions = $scope.category.byRate.tiers;
    }
};
```

and in html:

```
<div ng-repeat="categoryObject in categoryOptions track by $index">

<div>
```